# Alternative derivation of NVT partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, conservation-laws, phase-space, partition-function

I wanted to use an approach based on the Liouville equation to formulate the partition function of the NVT ensemble from its conservation laws. You can see some more about this approach in https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/epl/i1999-00139-0/pdf or https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1378321

However, I am going wrong somewhere. Here's why:

For a Hamiltonian system described in the canonical cartesian set of phase space variables $\eta=(r_i,p_i)$, the Liouville equation asserts the incompressibility of phase space, and can be used to obtain an expression for this density $f$ based on the conservation laws.
If the system has $n_c$ conservation laws of the general form:
$$\chi_k(\eta)=\lambda_k  , k=1,...,n_c$$
Then $f$ can be written as: (see for example https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1378321)
$$f(\eta)=\prod_{k=1..n_c}\delta(\chi_k(\eta)-\lambda_k)$$
$f(\eta)$ can be understood as a probability density to find a particle around $\eta$ in phase space. It allows us to write the partition function as the continuous sum of all probability densities:
$$Q=\int_\eta d\eta f(\eta)=\int_\eta d\eta \prod_k\delta(\chi_k(\eta)-\lambda_k) $$

In the case of the NVE ensemble where the Hamiltonian is the conserved quantity, it yields the familiar:
$$Q_{NVE}=\int_\eta d\eta\delta(H(\eta)-E)=\prod_i\int_{r_i} dr_i \prod_j\int_{p_j} dp_j \delta(H(r_i,p_j)-E) $$

I was wondering if I can apply this formulation to re-derive the NVT ensemble. Here is my attempt:
The conserved quantity is not the nergy anymore, but the statistical temperature, giving the conservation law:
$$\frac{1}{3N} \sum_{i=1..N} p_i^2/m=k_bT$$
where $N$ is the number of particles in the system (taken to all have the same mass to try and make things less hideous). Injecting this in the general formulation of Q:
$$Q_{NVT}=\prod_i\int_{r_i} dr_i \prod_j\int_{p_j} dp_j \delta\left(\frac{1}{3N} \sum_l p_l^2/m-k_bT\right)$$
I will now define the funtion $h(p_k)=\frac{1}{3N} p_k^2/m + \frac{1}{3N} \sum_{l\neq k} p_l^2/m-k_bT$, with roots $s_\pm=\pm\sqrt{3NmkT-\sum_{l\neq k} p_l^2} $. That allows me to rewrite the previous as:
$$Q_{NVT}=\prod_i\int_{r_i} dr_i \prod_{j\neq k}\int_{p_j} dp_j \left[\int dp_k \delta(h(p_k))\right]$$

and we know that, for a function h with roots $s_i$,
$$\delta(h(s))=\sum_i\frac{\delta(s-s_i)}{h'(s_i)}$$
Our function has 2 equal and opposite roots $s_+$ and $s_-$, so that the partition function will be a sum of the 2 corresponding terms. Let's write the term coming from $s_+$:

$$Q_+=\prod_i\int_{r_i} dr_i \prod_{j\neq k}\int_{p_j} dp_j \left[\int dp_k \frac{3mN}{2s_+}\delta(p_k-s_+)\right]$$

$$Q_+=\prod_i\int_{r_i} dr_i \prod_{j\neq k}\int_{p_j} dp_j \left[s_+ \frac{3mN}{2s_+}\right]$$
$$Q_+=\frac{3mN}{2}\widetilde{V_k}$$

where $\widetilde{V_k}$ is the "volume of phase space without $p_k$", or whatever. The root has simplified in the expression, so $Q_-$ should be the same, and our partition function would be:
$$Q_{NVT}=Q_++Q_-=3mN\widetilde{V_k}$$

Clearly, something is horribly wrong. This is definitely not the partition function of an NVT ensemble (the temperature has even cancelled out in the expression!)

So without a doubt, I made one or many despicable mistakes, either in my math or in my reasoning, or both. Could anyone show them to me?

Comment: Minor note: you have linked the same paper twice at the beginning

Comment: Thanks, I have edited this